# Le client « poll » le serveur toutes les minutes

Tags: traduction, informatique

Je ne sais pas si je fais de la francisation à outrance; mais je me suis retrouvé dans une situation ou je devais décrire le fonctionnement d'un système informatique en français.

Ce que je voulais dire c'est "*the client polls the server every minute*." Mes interlocuteurs venant du milieu technique m'ont compris.

Mais je me demande s'il y a une traduction non franglaise à cette phrase?

Comment: Je tiens à noter que l'usage d'anglicismes, bien que blâmé par les puristes, est très courant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Le client *sonde* le serveur toutes les minutes.

On pourrait dire aussi *interroge* pour un public moins technique.

Comment: C'est exactement ce que je cherchais. Merci.

Comment: +1 pour *interroge* que j'ai entendu à maintes reprises dans cet exact usage en milieu professionnel.

Comment: Je confirme pour *interroge*, j’ajoute que c’est le terme utilisé par la plus part des logiciels clients, particulièrement les courrielleurs.

Answer (score 4):

On pourrait également envisager : Le client *consulte* le serveur toutes les minutes.

Comment: Envisageable, mais *consulter* a aussi le sens de demander conseil à quelqu'un, alors que *sonder* à pour synonyme *fouiller* (ici, c'est dans les logs) ;  dans le même ordre d'idée il y a aussi *examiner* : "considérer avec attention, avec réflexion" avec de nombreux synonymes qui manifestent quelque chose de très approfondi, c'est une action que l'on entreprend en *examinant* le résultat des sondages ou des interrogatoires.

Answer (score 1):

Le client *requête* le serveur toutes les minutes. La forme nominale est assez diffusée (une requête client-serveur), du moins en France.